# Why wont my C program work

Tags: c

Hi i have been writing this c program and i have hit a wall it want let me call the sleep function. When i type sleep it just sits there until i exit it. Im' writing this program as a project in school and its based off the comedy skit the dark room.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
char a[100];
char *b = "go north";
char *c = "sleep";
char *d = "turn on light switch";
char *e = "check pockets";
char *f = "chuck pokets";

printf("\ntype the first word of every option\n");

        puts("\nYou awake to find yourself in a dark room\nwhat do you do\n");
        printf("go north                    sleep\nturn on the light switch                   why?\n");
        scanf("%s",a);

        int go_north() {
            char a[100];
            char *b = "find light switch";
            char *c = "check pockets";
            char *d = "chuck pockets";
            char *e = "weigh";
            char *f = "type";
            char *g = "abandon hope";
            char *h = "hint";
            char *i = "type";
            char *j = "click";
            char *k = "bag";

        puts("\noh you could go north\nif you knew where north was WITCH YOU CAN'T\nBECAUSE YOURE IN A DARK ROOM, ITS DARK AND YOURE IN A DARK ROOM WHAT ABOUT THIS DONT YOU BLOODY UNDERSTAND.");
        printf("\nfind the light switch     check pockets\nchuck pockets\n");
        scanf("%s",a);

        if(*a == *b) {
            puts("\ncongratulations you have\nfound out you would like to\nfind the light switch\nbut you have no idea\nhow to find the light switch,\nif onley there was some wayy");
            printf("\n\nweight                  type\nfind light switch                 abandon hope\n");
            scanf("%s",a);
        }

        if(*a == *e) {
        puts("\nogh dear did you\ntype that because I enfersized the word\nway ... you did dident you\nyoure gowing to have to learn\nthat every once in a while people\nare gowing to lie to you\nnot me though i will even give you a hint\n");
        printf("hint                click heals together 3x\nlook for light switch              bag\n");
        scanf("%s",a);
        }

        if(*a == *h) {
            puts("\nA HINT all right fine ... (waves christian cross in front of screen)");
        }

    }        

    if(*a == *b) {
        go_north(); 
    }

    int sleep(void) {

    printf("you awake to find youre self in a dark room");  

    }

    if(*a == *c) {  
        sleep();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask us wholesale to debug a problem for homework, and please give the question a more useful title that 'why doesn't my program work'

Comment: But a good place to start is that you recursively call your `sleep` function with no termination condition.

Comment: I really like this. Please continue with your progamming efforts.

Comment: Take your `sleep()` and `go_north()` function definitions **out** of `main()`

Comment: Your use of a nested functions mean your code is not standard C. The GNU C Compiler does support nested functions, but you shouldn't use that feature.

Comment: you might want to invest in a dictionary too, or is that part of the joke?

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcmp and repetition structures to improve your program

You can't compare strings using (*a == *b), this is equivalent to (a[0] == b[0]), with this you are comparing the first letter of each string

Your scanf can't read a line, so when you write - go north, it just takes go, and the other scanf gets north

I will not give you the answer because I think it's more fun and productive if you find it